# Accidentally committed and pushed 'database.yml' to Rails Git Repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, git-push

I am working on a Rails project!

Excuse for not adding `.gitignore`

I have accidentally committed and pushed '`database.yml`' in to my feature branch. A pull request was created from the `feature` branch to `master` branch a few days ago and is not yet merged. There are **multiple commits** done as part of this pull request and the commit containing 'database.yml' is the fourth last commit.

Others are also working as part of this project and they are merging the changes to master and we are pulling those changes in to our feature branch in-between. Thus, in our feature branch, we have got commits from others which are done after the faulty commit.

so I wish to do a '`git rm`' and '`git push`' the same file again to resolve this issue (as the PR is not yet merged). Will that create problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the `database.yml` that will be another commit on top, and nobody will be affected.

Notice, however, that the `database.yml` will still be part of the history and can be accessed via `git log`. If that file contains sensitive information, it will be findable by others.

Comment: Is there any way that we hide the sensitive data from a commit?

Comment: If somebody checked out the repo already, there is nothing you can do to prevent her from accessing the information. Your best bet then is to rotate the credentials. If you want to prevent others in the future from getting access to the file, you can use [this](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/). But be very careful when using this commands.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file from your local system then add the changes to a commit using 
`git add <FILE_PATH>` command and then commit and push the changes and it should be fine.

Comment: "and it should be fine" - until someone decides to check commit history.

Comment: Depends on what is 'fine'. If the goal is not having the file, when deploying to production - it will be fine. If it's to keep the contents secret - the beans were spilled, one should change those secrets as they can not be unpublished.

Comment: @meta: one can always rewrite history in the central repo, but if anyone managed to download the commits, then yeah, it's irreversible.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to remove it properly is to reverse the changes you made to the file and commit it.

Another, dirtier way, is to open the commit and remove the changes and force push it to the repo. But you need the proper rights for this. Others will also have problems if they try to pull changes then.